# Как в коде одного проекта решения инициировать сборку другого проекта?

Tags: c#, msbuild

В решение есть несколько проектов, и один из них (.Net Framework Console) выполняет функцию публикации главного. Как из кода инициировать пересборку Release? Я, конечно, могу найти расположение MsBuild и запустить его с помощью Process.Start, но может можно как-то интереснее сделать это?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен.

Comment: Ну если надо прям из кода и не хочется использовать `Process` можно попробовать [Microsoft.Build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/gg145008(v=vs.110))

Comment: Пояснений не будет? Зачем из кода инициировать пересборку проектов?

Comment: @UserName, как зачем? Мне нужно получить свежий исполняемый файл в папке \bin\Release . Кстати, `Microsoft.Build` действительно позволяет написать такой код, вот только, _он не работает_ надо уметь готовить)

Comment: @4per, да, может. То, что надо получить свежий исполняемый файл - понятно. Не понятна ситуация, которая требует подобной реализации. Вероятно можно найти более простой путь.

Comment: @UserName, пишу сценарий на c# публикации приложения. Работа с системой управления версиями, файловой системой, т.д.\т.п. и пересборка release

Comment: @4per, реализовать в виде [MSBuild Tasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing?view=vs-2017)? Позволит использовать имеющийся `C#` код, а так же всю функциональность `MSBuild` - [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871710/compiling-building-c-sharp-project-programmatically/49900728#49900728).

Comment: Ничего писать, возможно, и не надо для сборки. Завязаться на стандартный функционал `MSBuild`, а в остальном можно посредством [MSBuild Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing?view=vs-2017) и событийности реализовать соотвествующую цепочку действий.

Comment: Что-то решили в итоге? Описанный подход не подходит?

Comment: @UserName Пока использую `Process.Start` и `ExitCode`. В чём для меня польза от *MSBuild Task* я не уловил